# How to assign data to a variable given a pointer to it's address? C/C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I am new to C++!
I have a function to implement:

```
bool HashTableVoidIterator::next(const char * & key, void * & data)
```

and I am supposed to "store data in value data", so how to I store a character to key? (since it's passing me what I assume is a pointer to a memory address const `char *` `& key`)

Do I still write

```
key = 'a';
```

Comment: **Normally**, i.e. not necessarily in this situation, `char *key -> key = 'a'` is wrong so why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `key` is a pointer.  The function is passing as a reference so the pointer can be modified by the function.

You still need to deference:

```
*key = 'a';
```